# Paypal Express checkout giving error

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, magento-1.9

I am using paypal express checkout in magento store v1.9.2.2. I am getting errors sometimes while placing orders using paypal as payment method.
**Currently, I am using paypal sandbox account in test mode.**

1. Sometime, it takes me to different login screen and thereby gives error saying 'We're sorry  Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later'[image]
2. Sometime, it gives me error like 'use if pimp_rc(3198),use of pimp_rc(3011)....'[image]

Any possible reason for these kinda issue while paying through paypal?

Comment: were you able to solve this issue? I am facing the same problem and have no luck solving it so far

Answer (score 0):

I was facing exactly this issue with my paypal sandbox account. By inspecting the XHR calls I noticed one call getting failed everytime and that was to 
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/hermes/api/batch/setbuyer. Inspecting this specific call showed an error of "INVALID_SHIPPING_ADDRESS". So basically what I did is typed the same address upon checkout as that of the address present on my buyer(test account) account. Matching those two addresses solved the issue for me.